# Ant command not found in bash (windows 32bit)

Tags: bash, apache, github, ant, git-bash

I installed Apache ant using the link http://www.mkyong.com/ant/how-to-install-apache-ant-on-windows/

I am trying to build my files in git bash.
It shows the following error when I type ant:

```
bash:ant:command not found
```

I want to use `cd build` command.

Comment: Have you added all the environment variables, as specified at the page you are referring to? If so, can you check that `PATH` variable contains the path to the Ant binary directory? BTW, the page you refer to explains how to use Ant under plain windows, not from bash.

Comment: yes, i added all the environment variables that were required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your PATH when you are in the bash session.

```
echo $PATH
```

Don't forget that, after updating the PATH as mentioned in your link (through the Environment variable control panel), you need to open a *new* CMD session and launch `git-bash.exe` in order for that session to inherit the modified PATH.

```
cd c:\path\to\git
git-bash.exe
echo $PATH
```

The OP confirms in the comment that the PATH is now:

> d/Users/h169717/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin/:/mingw32/bin:/us‌​‌r/bin:/d/Users/h169717/bin:**/c/Program Files/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin**:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_72/bin:/c/Program Files/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

And `ant` is working.

Comment: the path is /d/Users/h169717/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin/:/mingw32?bin:/usr/bin:/d/Users/h169717/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files/Java:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: @SheenaAgrawal Then you did not add `%ANT_HOME%\bin` in your PATH as mentioned in your link. Do that, open a new windows, launch git-bash in it and check back if the issue persists.

Comment: open a simple CMD, go to your git installation folder and type git-bash.exe

Comment: I added %ANT_HOME%\bin in the path. But the path remains the same /d/Users/h169717/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin/:/mingw32?bin:/us‌​r/bin:/d/Users/h169717/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files/Java:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: OK, what does echo $PATH return now?

Comment: and in the new window. when i type git-bash.exe it says bash: git-bash.exe: command not found

Comment: Did you go first where git is installed?

Comment: echo $PATH returns /d/Users/h169717/bin:/mingw32/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin/:/mingw32/bin:/us‌r/bin:/d/Users/h169717/bin:/c/Program Files/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_72/bin:/c/Program Files/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl